# How can I run IPython within Emacs under Cygwin for my Enthought Python Distrubution installation?

Tags: emacs, cygwin, ipython, enthought

I like Emacs, but I'm stuck using Windows 7.  I've installed Cygwin and can use Emacs for basic editing tasks.  I can set Emacs up to run the Cygwin installation of IPython, but I'd rather run the Enthought Python Distribution version of IPython.

Following advice from [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs), I added the following to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(when (executable-find "ipython")
  (setq
   python-shell-interpreter "/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/ipython.bat"
   python-shell-interpreter-args ""
   python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
   python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
   python-shell-completion-setup-code
   "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
   python-shell-completion-module-string-code
   "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
   python-shell-completion-string-code
   "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n"))
```

Note I modified the third line to point to `ipython.bat`.  I then start the interpreter, which loads EPD, but I get the following errors and can't do anything:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\username\My Documents\python\<ipython-input-2-6552ae2ca310> in <module>()
----> 1 __pyfile = open('''/tmp/py6644bAS''');exec(compile(__pyfile.read(), '''/tmp/py6644bAS''', 'exec'));__pyfile.close()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/py6644bAS'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\username\My Documents\python\<ipython-input-3-492fce3681b4> in <module>()
----> 1 __pyfile = open('''/tmp/py6644XOK''');exec(compile(__pyfile.read(), '''/tmp/py6644XOK''', 'exec'));__pyfile.close()

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/py6644XOK'
```

Any ideas or other ways to allow me to run EPD's IPython installation in Emacs via Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Here a way how to tweak python-mode.el working with Anaconda - not exactly what you are looking for, however it might provide some hints:

```
(defun ipython (&optional argprompt)
  "Start an IPython interpreter.

Optional \\[universal-argument] prompts for options to pass to the IPython interpreter. See `py-python-command-args'. "
  (interactive "P")
  (setq py-ipython-command "C:\\Users\\MYNAME\\Anaconda\\Scripts\\ipython.exe")
  (py-shell argprompt nil py-ipython-command))
```

Comment: That does help to an extent: I also have Enthought Canopy installed, and it has an ipython.exe script instead of ipython.bat.